# Compress video in android using mp4parser

Tags: android, mp4parser

I was reading about the mp4Parser library on the internet and was unable to find any tutorial through which i can compress a video stored on the sdcard. All the tutorials links i find on the web gives a 404 error.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you! Try using **FFMpeg Library** which is the **best library for video compression**!!!

Comment: is it free to use? The only problem i found out with it that you need to public your app's source code.